# BASH - Get number from a file and use it

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a test.txt file that looks like this:

```
flask=1.0.1
control=1.0.1
device=1.0.1
```

Now, I want to create an if statement that if flask=1.0.1, do something and if flash=1.0.1_hotfix do something else.

I tried with `grep -iFq` but no luck, I am newbie to bash and also to programming.

Can anyone show me a doc that explains how to do so? It's really simple task.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4):

With `bash` and `if`:

```
source test.txt

if [[ $flask == 1.0.1 ]]; then
  echo "do something"
fi

if [[ $flask == 1.0.1_hotfix ]]; then
  echo "do something else"
fi
```

Or with `bash` and `case`:

```
source test.txt

case $flask in
1.0.1)
  echo "do something"
  ;;
1.0.1_hotfix)
  echo "do something else"
  ;;
esac
```

Or in a denser presentation:

```
source test.txt

case $flask in
         1.0.1) echo "do something" ;;
  1.0.1_hotfix) echo "do something else" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Note to the unwary (or the newbie): this will execute any commands in `test.txt`.  For this to work, `test.txt` must be valid shell code and not contain any commands with undesirable side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Grep is fine, just notice that `flask=1.0.1` is a substring of `flask=1.0.1_hotfix`, so you need to do full string comparison or check for the string end.

```
flask=$( grep ^flask= test.txt )
if [ "$flask" == flask=1.0.1 ] ; then
    ...
elif [ "$flask" == flask=1.0.1_hotfix ] ; then
    ....
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I've understood you correctly?

```
[root@212-24-57-104 Build]# cat 1
flask=1.0.1
control=1.0.1
device=1.0.1
[root@212-24-57-104 Build]# cat ez.sh
#!/bin/bash
a=( $(cat 1) )
for ver in "${a[@]}"
do 
    if [ $(echo "${ver}" | awk -F= '{print $NF}') == "1.0.1" ]
    then 
        echo "Do something virh $ver"
    else 
        echo "Do anything else with $ver"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Populating the `a` array like this is risky, due to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion). This is safer: `mapfile -t a < filename`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other options:

1. use `grep` to get the value

   ```
   flask_value=$( grep -oP '^flask=\K.*' test.txt )
   case $flask_value in 
       1.0.1) ... ;;
       # etc
   esac
   ```
2. iterate over the file with just bash:

   ```
   while IFS="=" read var value; do
       if [[ $var == "flask" ]]; then
           case $value in 
               1.0.1) ... ;;
               # etc
           esac
       fi
   done < test.txt
   ```